# What's the difference between anonymous and security in the security.yml file?

Tags: symfony, security

Everything is in the title. I want to know the difference between both annotations. Sometimes I see anonymous and sometimes security. And I can't tell the difference.

Thank you guys for the help !

Answer (score 1):

The `security` parameter is used to totally disable/enable the features of the security component inside a firewall.

For example, the default `dev` firewall has the `security` parameter set to `false`.
That involves that the security is totally disabled on the routes handled by this firewall.

The `anonymous` parameter make non-loggedin users authenticated as `Anonymous`, so it keep all features of the security component enabled.
You can use security-related features (e.g. allowing/restricting routes) regardless the value of the `anonymous` parameter.

Read more in the [documentation of the Security component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html).